# Star Trek: transporter as a weapon/defense

Tags: star-trek

Since transporter beam cannot bypass the shields, why can't they be used to lift things (torpedo, antimatter-core) to edge of the other ship's shield so they don't miss?

As defense: wouldn't the transporter array be useful when mounted on the edge of the ship, so they just transport anything incoming? Torpedoes back at enemy shields, transporting armor plates from another part to the offended part, transporting a transporter so they can chain-transport to large distances and make a warp-interrupting field.

Comment: For one, you can't get a transporter lock on a fast moving missile.

Answer (score 2):

There was a DS9 episode featuring an experimental rifle that transported the bullet close to the victim, allowing an assassin to remain out of sight.